# Using array in WHERE clause of SQL statement using access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an array ListBoxContents(), it will contain the items like '15', '16','25'..upto 10 items. I'm trying to retrieve data in the column *Bnumber* where data of length >6 and starting with('15', '16','25'...) i.e those items specified in listbox .And trying to query these listbox items in where cluase of the sql statement

Table column Bnumber contains

```
 Bnumber
152
156
1523
16417
AA454
CC654
18A16
1826
18A16
25A76
54A16
54235A68
```

My VBA code

```
Private Sub arraywhere()
Dim qry As String 
Dim Size As Integer
Size = Form_Input_From.lstdigits.ListCount - 1
ReDim ListBoxContents(0 To Size) As String
ReDim LContents(0 To 30) As String       
Dim m As Integer    
For m = 0 To Size
    ListBoxContents(m) = Form_Input_From.lstdigits.ItemData(m)
Next m  


For m = 0 To Size
     qry = "SELECT col1,col2,Bnumber " & _
    "FROM table WHERE (Len([table].[Bnumber]))>6) AND (Left
     ([table].[Bnumber],2))=(" & ListBoxContents(m) & ");"
Next m   

Debug.Print qry    

Application.CurrentDb.QueryDefs("[arrayqry]").sql = qry
DoCmd.OpenQuery "[arrayqry]"

End Sub
```

But my WHERE clause reads only last array item only. How do i specify array in where clause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like

```
" ...  ([table].[Bnumber],2)) in ('" & Join(ListBoxContents,"','") & "');"
```

Comment: Tim, as far as I know, syntax should be `In ('12','22','33','15');`, but `Join` gives me `In ('12,22,33,15');`

Comment: @simoco - typing on my phone, so not up to my usual standard - see edit

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `qry` to a new statement with each iteration of your for loop. Instead you need to concatenate a string based on your list box contents that will look like `("x", "y", "z")` and replace `=` with `in`.

Finish by setting your query *once* it will look similar to this:

```
qry = "SELECT col1,col2,Bnumber " & _
"FROM table WHERE (Len([table].[Bnumber]))>6) AND (Left
 ([table].[Bnumber],2)) in (" & commaSeperatedContents & ");"
```

Where `commaSeperatedContents` is a String that is like `("x", "y", "z")` but of course has your values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Dim inPart As String

For m = 0 To Size
    inPart = inPart & "'" & ListBoxContents(m) & "',"
Next m
inPart = Left(inPart, Len(inPart) - 1)

qry = "SELECT col1,col2,Bnumber " & _
   "FROM [table] WHERE Len([table].[Bnumber])>6 AND " & _
   "Left([table].[Bnumber],2) In (" & inPart & ");"
Debug.Print qry

CurrentDb.QueryDefs("[arrayqry]").SQL = qry
DoCmd.OpenQuery "arrayqry"
```

Answer (score 0):

The list of items in your array actually seems to be coming from the `Form_Import_From_PMT.lstdigits` control. Is this control bound to a data source? If so, you can simply join your `table` to that data source with a join clause that specifies that only rows with `Bnumber` values starting with the digits in the joined table are to be selected:

```
select col1, col2, Bnumber
from table as t
inner join tblDigits as d
on left(t.Bnumber, 2) = d.Digits
where len(t.Bnumber) > 6
```

If the control is *not* bound to a data source, then bind it now (creating a new table `tblDigits` to hold the digits, as shown above), and you'll be able to use the above query.

In short, data binding is how you 'use an array in a `where` clause' in Access.